# Enumeration best practices

Tags: .net, enums

I'm defining a couple of classes to represent transactions and i need to define a TransactionType enum.

A prototype for my class is:

```
public class Transaction
{
    public enum Type { Income, Outcome }

    public DateTime Date { get; set;}
    public Type Type { get; set;}
    public decimal Amount { get; set;}
}
```

Some people would say that TransactionType enum should be declared on namespace scope, but for those i'would say that this Type is only related to the Transaction so IMO it should be declared inside the class.
If i declare it in the class, there's a compiler error in field Type declaration.
Should i name it Types? Guess not too because i need to refer Income as a Type and not as Types.

Please say what you think about this topic, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would try to define *any* type with the smallest visibility possible. In your case `public enum Type { Income, Outcome }` is public so it doesn't really matter. If it was private then you would keep it as a nested type.

Best practices would be to keep all public types in separate files.

Comment: But this enum is only to describe one field type inside my class. It's only refering that class.

Comment: If so, you can make it private and keep it in. If you need it public best would be to move it to a separate file.

Answer (score 2):

`Type` is one of the most important classes of System.Reflection. I would use another name because it is very ambigious.

Comment: Imagine another sample, the same problem with different names. My problem is simple as: Singular or Plural naming inside or outside class definition!

Comment: As already said by others, if it is private, I would place it inside the class, otherwise outside. Plural or singular? I mostly use singular, I find it more nice. But this is only my personal liking, I dont know if there are some deeper thoughs about this.

Answer (score 1):

Call the enum `TransactionType` and move it outside the class. That name is just as descriptive as `Transaction.Type`, and it solves the naming conflict problem.

Comment: But this enum is only to describe one field type inside my class. It's only refering that class.

Answer (score 0):

Make it `TransactionType` then. It will be still short enough yet it will make your code much more readable.

Comment: Sergey, but that is not redundant?

Comment: Well, not for me :) Naming is mostly a matter of personal taste and corporate coding guidelines (if you have any). I've just suggested how I will name this enum.